# adding show.rjs causes error on show.haml page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, rjs

I have a controller that I want to be able to respond to html or to js requests. 
Currently, I have a HAML page that shows information about a document. Simply by adding a show.rjs file to the views/documents folder, I start getting errors.

Here is what renders:

```
try { } catch (e) { alert('RJS error:\n\n' + e.toString()); alert(''); throw e }
```

Here is my controller:

```
def show
    @document = Document.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @document }
      format.js
    end
end
```

here is show.rjs:

```
logger.debug "what the heck!"
```

Anyone have any idea why this might not be working?

Answer (score 1):

Rename it `show.js.erb`

Change your content to `<% logger.debug "what the heck!"%>`

I think the latest is enough though.

Comment: But what I've described above should work though, right? I'm trying to figure out what that got broken.

Comment: I don't remember whether or not you require <%%> in rjs views.